# How to fix flex boxes in windows Safari 5.1.7?

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I'm using flex boxes to handle my website layouts. but apparently the safari version for windows (5.1.7) is old and all flex boxes destroyed ,,,

In mac system that version is 12.x and works right

Is a trick to handle this problem ?

Or always I've problem with windows version of safari ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You don't. Long answer:

The Safari Browser for Windows was [discontinued 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_(web_browser)), so over 7 years ago. And it isn't supported by Apple anymore, meaning anyone who uses this browser won't have many working sites to begin with. And they will also have to think about an update plan because of security reasons. So there isn't really any reason to support Safari on Windows anymore (even tough I'm naturally all for supporting also older browsers)

Answer (score -1):

Most browser specific css issues can be fixed by using autoprefixer during build time.
Give it a try..

https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer

Or just paste that code here and copy output:

https://autoprefixer.github.io/